# Regex & JS how to regex match a string between " and partial patterns (match first few characters and no special pattern)

Tags: node.js, regex

I been been struggled to make this regex and would love to get some help here.

So I want to match an url string if it is

- between ""
- start with "https://example.com
- no space, tab, newline within the ""
- not contain patterns like `.dont_match1` or `.dont_match1/` at the end

then replace `example.com` to `example2.com`.

for example,

```
bla ...... "https://example.com/content/a.dont_match1" 
bla ...... "https://example.com/content/a.dont_match2"
```

No match

```
href="https://example.com/"
```

Matched and replace to =>href="https://example2.com/"

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com adasd /" />
```

No match because of the stupid space

```
<link rel="manifest" href="https://example.com/a/asd/aaaa">
```

Matched and replace to =><link rel="manifest" href="https://example2.com/a/asd/aaaa">

All these lines are in a file.

Been stuck on these for a while, have tried quite a few, but not working well

- `(=".*)(example.com)([^\s])*"`
- `(=".*)(example.com)([^\s|^.dont_match1 |^.dont_match2])*"`

Comment: Try  `.replace(/("https:\/\/)example\.com(?![^\s"]*\.dont_match1\/?")([^\s"]*")/g, '$1exampl2.com$2')`

Comment: Thanks! @WiktorStribiżew
How do I update the regex to have not end with ".dont_match1" AND ".dont_match2"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
/("https:\/\/)example\.com(?![^\s"]*\.(?:dont_match1|dont_match2)\/?")([^\s"]*")/g
```

Repace with `$1example2.com$2`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZA0shH/1).

*Details*

- `("https:\/\/)` - Group 1 (`$1`): `"https://` string
- `example\.com` - an `example.com` string
- `(?![^\s"]*\.(?:dont_match1|dont_match2)\/?")` - a negtive lookahead that fails the match if there are zero or more chars other than whitespace and `"` followed with a `.`, then either `dont_match1` or `dont_match2`, then an optional `/` and then a `"` immediately to the right of the current location
- `([^\s"]*")` - Group 2 (`$2`): zero or more chars other than whitespace and `"` and then a `"` char.

JavaScript demo:

```js
const array = ['bla ...... "https://example.com/content/a.dont_match1"', 
'bla ...... "https://example.com/content/a.dont_match2"', 
'href="https://example.com/"    '];
const rx = /("https:\/\/)example\.com(?![^\s"]*\.(?:dont_match1|dont_match2)\/?")([^\s"]*")/g;
array.forEach( x => 
  console.log(x, '=>', x.replace(rx, '$1example2.com$2'))
 )
```